# Get redirected ULR with Python to get access code

Tags: python, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

This question has been asked several times, and didn't find any answer that works for me. I am using request library to get the redirect url, however my code returns the original url. If I click on the link it takes few second before I get the redirect url and then manually extract the code, but I need to get this information by python.
Here is my code. I have tried response.history but it returns empty list.

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&scope=user.read%20chat.read&state=12345")
print(response)
print('-------------------')
print(response.url)
```

I am trying to get the code by following this Microsoft documention "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user".
Here are the links that I found in stack over flow and didn't solve my issue.
[To get redirected URL with requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503861/to-get-redirected-url-with-requests) , [How to get redirect url code with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54406302/how-to-get-redirect-url-code-with-python) ( this is probably very close to my situation), [how to get redirect url using python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070821/how-to-get-redirect-url-using-python-requests) and this one [Python Requests library redirect new url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any luck to get redirected url back by using requests as mentioned in previous posts. But I was able to work around this using webbrowser library and then get the browser history using sqlite 3 and was able to get the result that I was looking for.
I had to go through postman and add postman url into my app registration for using Graph API, but if you simply want to get redirected url you can follow the same code and you should get redirected url.

let me know if there are better solutions.

here is my code:

```
import webbrowser
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import shutil

webbrowser.open("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&scope=user.read%20chat.read&state=12345")
#source file is where the history of your webbroser is saved, I was using chrome, but it should be the same process if you are using different browser
source_file = 'C:\\Users\\{your_user_id}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History'
# could not directly connect to history file as it was locked and had to make a copy of it in different location
destination_file = 'C:\\Users\\{user}\\Downloads\\History'
time.sleep(30) # there is some delay to update the history file, so 30 sec wait give it enough time to make sure your last url get logged
shutil.copy(source_file,destination_file) # copying the file.
con = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\\{user}\\Downloads\\History')#connecting to browser history
cursor = con.execute("SELECT * FROM urls")
names = [description[0] for description in cursor.description]
urls = cursor.fetchall()
con.close()
df_history = pd.DataFrame(urls,columns=names)
last_url = df_history.loc[len(df_history)-1,'url']
print(last_url)

>>https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/browser-callback?code={code}&state=12345&session_state={session_state}#
```